# What text-to-speech libraries are available in Ruby?

Tags: library, ruby, speech-synthesis

What text-to-speech libraries are available in Ruby? I'm looking for libraries with explicit Ruby APIs, and don't want to deal with JSON, XML-RPC, or system calls.

Answer (score 2):

Text-to-speech libraries for Ruby include:

- [espeak-ruby](https://github.com/dejan/espeak-ruby) - Wrapper for [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/)
- [FestivalTTS](https://github.com/spejman/festivaltts4r) - Wrapper for [Festival](http://www.festvox.org/festival/)
- [Google Cloud Text-to-Speech API](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docs-samples/tree/master/texttospeech)
- [Google Translate service](https://github.com/c2h2/tts)
- [mac-say](https://rubygems.org/gems/mac-say) - Wrapper for [`say`](https://ss64.com/osx/say.html) command on Mac
- [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/11/02/outbound-text-to-speech-voice-call-ruby-on-rails-dr/)
- [Pollynomial](https://github.com/chezou/pollynomial) - Wrapper for [AWS Polly](https://aws.amazon.com/polly/)
- [Twilio](http://alexpatriquin.github.io/twilio-text-to-speech-in-rails-4/)
- [Voice RSS](http://www.voicerss.org/sdk/ruby.aspx)

You can also send text to a terminal and use various [terminal-based libraries](https://askubuntu.com/q/501910/396228) or one of the many available [text-to-speech APIs](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/text-to-speech/api)